# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline: how to deal with requests to expired assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Once you've set up an application with the asset pipeline, it might generate an image for you with a URL like this (signature truncated):

```
http://mysite.com/assets/logo-1b2b3c.png
```

Then, when you change the asset or update the global asset version, you end up with something like this:

```
http://mysite.com/assets/logo-2b3c1a.png
```

Now, some people will still be sending requests to the old asset. Under what I understand to be the default Rails 3.1 deploy, these would just 404. That doesn't seem very friendly. It would be nicer to either 301 to the new asset or just deliver the new asset straight up.

Is there some built-in way to do this, or do I have to implement my own asset missing feature?

Comment: Nobody should be sending requests for the old assets. If they're viewing cached HTML, they should be using cached assets.

Comment: I agree with @meagar. I'm very curious about the circumstances where this would ever happen. Can you show how this is happening?

Comment: @Andrew Vit: While I agree that this shouldn't happen, it can. The case that I encountered for when this happens is if somebody hotlinks an image including the hash, hotlinks that needed to be supported. Sure, it would have been better to anticipate people hotlinking and offering an unversioned asset path, but the time, we couldn't go back and notify 500 external sites to change their links, so in the reality of the production world, we had to do something like this.

Comment: @steven People shouldn't be hot-linking your resources. This is the very definition of not-your-problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented it myself:

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'assets/:id.:format' => 'assets#show'
end

class AssetsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    asset_without_digest = "#{params[:id].gsub /-[0-9a-f]{32}$/, ''}.#{params[:format]}"
    new_path = ActionView::Base.new.image_path(asset_without_digest)
    if url_for(params).include? new_path
      head 404
    else
      redirect_to new_path, :status => 301
    end
  end
end
```